# Using json with DataServiceContext

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I have created a custom proxy inheriting from DataServiceContext to work with my WCF data service. It appears that, at least in past years, you could not set the accept header to allow json to be used rather than XML. I have a REQUIREMENT to do just this and was hoping there was some way to do this now without having to write a proxy from the ground-up.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently WCF Data Service client library doesn't support JSON. So there's no way to do this.
You could use OData Library which is a lower level library to consume OData, which does support reading JSON payloads. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/14/introducing-the-odata-library.aspx.

Comment: Thanks @Vitek. Looks great but I need something that is not in CTP. I suppose I will need to build my own proxy library.

Comment: The OData Library should RTM soon (less than 2 months), so maybe you could use it still.